# Angular rxjs Observables to find first alive server

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to implement something like what the plugin `promiseAny` allows but for Observables, where the first to get a response back is the 'winner'.  Specifically for Angular `http.get()`s for different possible servers.

I have the following, however it is returning a result for all of the merged Observables that represent `http.get` to each server.  One of the servers is alive and one I know is dead.  Yet the value being returned from the subscription has 2 values and the results don't indicate that one is up and the other down.  The subscription (`http.get()`) doesn't seem to be firing.  How should I write this?

This is for Angular 7.2.

```
import {merge} from 'rxjs';
import {take} from 'rxjs/operators';

async getActiveServer(servers: string[]): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        merge(this.buildObservables(servers)).pipe(take(1))
            .subscribe((value) => {
                // .flatMap((value) => {
                console.log(`observable - value: ${JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)}`);
                if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 0) {
                    resolve(this.findServer(value[0]));
                } else {
                    reject('cannot find server as response is not an array - it is: ${value}');
                }
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(`observable - error: ${error}`);
            });
    });

private async buildObservables(servers: string[]): Promise<any> {
    const observablesBatch = [];
    for (const server of servers) {
        observablesBatch.push(this.http.get<any>(server + '/health/alive?server=' + server));
    }
    return observablesBatch;
}
```

`findServer()` deals with the separate problem that I'm getting back a nested object structure.  This method walks the structure to find the url and extracts the desired information from the string.

The value printed from `console.log(`observable - value:` is something like:

```
observable - value: [
  {
    "_isScalar": false,
    "source": {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "_isScalar": false,
        "source": {
          "_isScalar": true,
          "value": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/health/alive?server=http://localhost:8080",
            "body": null,
            "reportProgress": false,
            "withCredentials": false,
            "responseType": "json",
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
              "normalizedNames": {},
              "lazyUpdate": null,
              "headers": {}
            },
            "params": {
              "updates": null,
              "cloneFrom": null,
              "encoder": {},
              "map": null
            },
            "urlWithParams": "http://localhost:8080/health/alive?server=http://localhost:8080"
          }
        },
        "operator": {
          "concurrent": 1
        }
      },
      "operator": {}
    },
    "operator": {}
  },
  {
    "_isScalar": false,
    "source": {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "_isScalar": false,
        "source": {
          "_isScalar": true,
          "value": {
            "url": "https://remoteServer.net//health/alive?server=https://remoteServer.net/",
            "body": null,
            "reportProgress": false,
            "withCredentials": false,
            "responseType": "json",
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
              "normalizedNames": {},
              "lazyUpdate": null,
              "headers": {}
            },
            "params": {
              "updates": null,
              "cloneFrom": null,
              "encoder": {},
              "map": null
            },
            "urlWithParams": "https://remoteserver.net//health/alive?server=https://remoteserver.net/"
          }
        },
        "operator": {
          "concurrent": 1
        }
      },
      "operator": {}
    },
    "operator": {}
  }
]
```

As you can see i tried a `flatMap()` but this didn't work in the time I allocated to it.

How should I write this?

---

### 1. I provided an answer of what worked based on @Phix's answer.

### 2. Edits - the solution using `race` as suggested by @Adrian Brand.

I like it (if it worked) but it doesn't work.  I don't have time to work this out and according to Adrian's linked post this should work.  The syntax error I am getting is `Property subscribe does not exist on MonoTypeOperatorFunction<any>`.

THIS DOES NOT WORK BUT IT WOULD BE NICE IF IT DID (though need to add filtering or similar).

```
async getActiveServer(servers: string[]): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    race(...this.buildObservables(servers))
        .subscribe(r => {
            console.log('Found a live server:', r);
            resolve(r.alive);
        }, () => console.warn('Nothing is alive.'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is around the direction you're after.  I first thought `race` might work, but that will return whatever resolves first, errors included.

```js
import { merge, of, race } from 'rxjs'; 
import { first, filter, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Combine all http requests
merge(...buildObservables())
  .pipe(
    // Only let through those that have a good response code
    filter((server: any) => server.response < 400),
    // Just take the first one
    first(),
  )
  .subscribe(r => console.log('Found a live server:', r), () => console.warn('Nothing is alive.'))

// Builds mock server responses
function buildObservables() {
  const responses = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    responses.push(mockResponse(`http://sub${i}.example.com/api/v1`));
  }

  return responses;
}

function mockResponse(url: string) {
  const timeout = Math.round(Math.random() * 3000)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() < .5) {
        resolve({
          server: url,
          response: 200
        })
      } else {
        reject({
          server: url,
          response: 500
        })
      }
    }, timeout)
  })
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fjgorb?devtoolsheight=60)

Comment: Awesome thanks, the main solution you provided was to use `...this.buildObservables(servers)`.  I like the use of `filter`.  I was thinking I'd use `takeUntil(server => server.response < 400)`.  I just tried and I can't just slot it in-place as it receives different arguments (and I am not going to push forward with this as i have a working solution).  Thanks again!

Comment: I provided a full solution as an answer based on your response.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using race instead?

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/race.html

Comment: This looks like it might be more succinct.  However with the following I am getting a syntax error on the `subscribe` that race is returning a `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<any>` and that doesn't have `subscribe` method.    I will post what I tried in to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a what works based on **@Phix**'s answer (be sure to upvote them):

```
async getActiveServer(servers: string[]): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            merge(...this.buildObservables(servers))
                .pipe(
                    filter((server: any) => server.hasOwnProperty('alive')),
                    first()
                )
                .subscribe(r => {
                    console.log('Found a live server:', r);
                    resolve(r.alive);
                }, () => console.warn('Nothing is alive.'));
        });
    }

    private buildObservables(servers: string[]): Observable<any>[] {
        const observablesBatch: Observable<any>[] = [];
        for (const server of servers) {
            observablesBatch.push(this.http.get<any>(server + '/health/alive?server=' + server));
        }
        return observablesBatch;
    }
```

Note that the `alive` endpoint on my server is returning:

```
async alive(server): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve({alive: server});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to mold it closer to the original question!

Comment: I always try to dot the eye's and cross the tee's.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a raceWithFilter static operator:

```js
function raceWithFilter<T>(observables: ObservableInput<T>[], predicate: (value: T) => boolean): Observable<T> {
  const results: Observable<[T, boolean]>[] = observables.map(x => from(x).pipe(map(y => [y, predicate(y)])));
  const none$ = zip(...results).pipe(filter(x => x.every(y => !y[1])), map(() => <T>null));
  const race$ = race(results.map(x => concat(x.pipe(filter(y => y[1])), NEVER))).pipe(map(x => x[0]));
  return merge(race$, none$);
}
```